# Showing images on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply the same as what is on this site for the images and I want to know what I need. Thank you
https://www.mackenzieconstruction.com/our-work/ if there is any resources or example can help me please send

Answer (score 1):

You can use AOS library which does exactly that.

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: but i don't use npm i work with a static files

Comment: CDN links: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>` `<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">`